# SQL Server 2005 Linked server not finding tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a linked server where I can clearly see all the databases and tables, so I know the server is properly linked. However, when I try to execute a query, it says invalid object name, at the linked server's table.

The linked server is aliased as TCS, therefore, my query takes that table as

```
FROM [TCS].dbo.table as b
```

I have also tried including the database name also as FROM [TCS\db1].dbo.table.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including the DB name like so:

```
FROM [TCS].db1.dbo.table as b
```

I don't think you can specify the DB using a slash.

I would also check to make sure your security settings for the linked server are allowing your account to connect.  [This article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3691721/Setting-up-a-Linked-Server-for-a-Remote-SQL-Server-Instance.htm) touches on how to do that.

Comment: Indeed, I was about to post about just finding this out! Thanks Abe!

Answer (score 0):

either:

1. the user (used for the link) doesn't have access to the table; Grant access;
2. the default DB on the server doesn't have the table. You have to change it to the relevant one or included in the db in the name: `[TCS].`**DATABASE**`.dbo.table as b`;